# Android Kotlin - QR scanner detecting QR code but not redirecting to default browser

Tags: android, kotlin

When a QR code is detected the integrated camera will close but nothing happens afterwards

```
    binding.scanQR.setOnClickListener() {
        val scanner = IntentIntegrator(this)
        scanner.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
        scanner.setBeepEnabled(false)
        scanner.initiateScan()
    }

    val result = intent.getStringExtra(RESULT)

    if (result != null) {
        if (result.contains("https://") || result.contains("http://")) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result))
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            binding.scanQR.text = result.toString()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `onActivityResult` method in your activity. This method is called when the scanner finishes and returns the result.

Try this code:

```
binding.scanQR.setOnClickListener {
    val scanner = IntentIntegrator(this)
    scanner.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
    scanner.setBeepEnabled(false)
    scanner.initiateScan()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (result != null && result.contents != null) {
        val qrResult = result.contents
        if (qrResult.contains("https://") || qrResult.contains("http://")) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(qrResult))
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            binding.scanQR.text = qrResult
        }
    }
}
```